# XAMPP with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

So, I'm fairy new to web development, and I've created some HTML pages and put them into Codeigniter. I'm now trying to use XAMPP to host the site from my local machine and would like to link the Codeigniter code to it, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I've tried to use linking code in the XAMPP index.php file but I'm unsure of the correct way to do this (since all my previous attempts have failed). Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what are/how are you linking, did you try accessing your files via localhost?

Comment: JMax, I was unaware (look at my post count...), thanks for awaring me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to link the existing `index.php` to your codeIgniter code. The existing `index.php` is only a place holder.

Place all your CI files into the www root of your XAMPP server such that CI's `index.php` replaces the already existent `index.php`

Your current folder structure should be something like this

```
- www  
-- index.php (the placeholder index.php)
```

Your new folder structure should be like this

```
-- www
---- index.php (CI's index.php)  
---- application  
---- system
```